# Is it possible to query process information from Linux kernel directly?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, proc

I know `pgrep`, `top`, and `ps` all query `/proc` filesystems. So far so good. Yet what got me thinking is that in the past there was no `/proc` filesystem. Even nowadays, Mac OS X, as far as I know, has no `/proc` filesystem, yet `top` still accesses process info, which sugggests to me such info should be coming from kernel directly. My question, however, is specific to Linux. Which libraries and/or syscalls can be used to query process information directly, bypassing `/proc` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to query process information from the Linux kernel directly — by reading files under `/proc`. This is the way it's done on Linux, Solaris and several other Unix variants.

Ancient Unix systems had a `ps` command that was setuid root and mapped some kernel memory (through [`/dev/kmem`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kmem&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) or similar) and parsed kernel data structures. This required `ps` to have privileges (dangerous) and to be tied to the exact kernel version (inconvenient).

On modern *BSD systems, `ps` works by calling the [`sysctl`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) function, which in turn makes system calls to retrieve information formatted as structures defined by a binary format. MacOS uses the same mechanism.

Linux does not have this BSD interface. It uses procfs and sysfs to allow userland to retrieve information from the kernel. Where BSD marshals information in a binary format retrieved by a special-purpose system call, Linux marshals information as strings retrieved through ordinary file access to a special-purpose filesystem. It would be possible to use the same method as in ancient Unix systems, but nobody does it because it's such an inferior method (requires privileges and requires updating whenever the kernel data structures change).

Comment: In general, BSD `sysctl` actually does _not_ incorporate multiple processes, or even a single process, mapping any areas of shared memory.  Rather, it is just several thousand `get`/`set` system calls all rolled into one.  Specifically, the FreeBSD `sysctl` for `CTL_KERN`-`KERN_PROC` involves no memory mapping.

Comment: @JdeBP Oh, thank you. I thought that sysctl used KVM. It's documented as a libc function, not as a system call. So it's a system call on all *BSD then, marshalling a binary structure into the caller's memory?

Comment: The package that provides `ps` is called `procps` because it was an alternative, coexisting for a time with the older package called `kmem-ps`.

Answer (score 3):

Before the advent of the /proc filesystem, psutils read the information directly via /dev/kmem, the kernel memory pseudo device. Obviously only certain versions of ps worked with any given kernel version, which was one argument in favor of /proc. (Being human readable, and easier access to kernel structures for things like perl scripts are arguably bigger benefits.)